# Error "Unexpected token near function FindProxyFor" while installing Angular CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

After installing node.js in my machine, I tried to install Angular CLI in node.js command prompt:

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

But it's reporting a JSON error:

[image]

How to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have the required versions of node and npm installed?

Comment: C:\>node -v
**v9.1.0**

C:\>npm -v
**5.5.1**

Comment: Btw, package should be `@angular/cli`

Comment: Same error I got while using `@angular/cli` @pzaenger

Comment: whats inside C:\users\user\appData\Roaming\npm-cache\logs\-debug.log? also, try with `npm install @angular/cli --save`

Comment: I checked with Proxy server connection also. But in my IE & chrome there is no proxy server address.